# fastai throwing a "training set empty" error when the directories are not empty

Tags: python, exception, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, fast-ai

I'm trying to build a classifier with both a training and a test set.  However, FastAI is throwing a `UserWarning: Your training set is empty` error despite the fact that both training and test sets are not empty. This is the output of my terminal commands to see how many items each folder has:

```
%cd Food-101/images/train/
!ls -1 | wc -l

%cd ../test
!ls -1 | wc -l

%cd ../../

/content/Food-101/images/train
75750
/content/Food-101/images/test
25250
/content/Food-101
```

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

from fastai import *
from fastai.vision import *
from fastai.callbacks.hooks import *
from pathlib import Path
from numba import vectorize
from subprocess import call, run
import os, git, glob, shutil

file_parse = r'/([^/]+)_\d+\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$'

np.random.seed(42)
data = ImageDataBunch.from_folder(path, train= path + '/images/train', test=path + '/images/test', valid_pct=0.2, ds_tfms=get_transforms(), size=224)
data.normalize(imagenet_stats)
```

And this is the error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fastai/data_block.py:458: UserWarning: Your training set is empty. If this is by design, pass `ignore_empty=True` to remove this warning.
  warn("Your training set is empty. If this is by design, pass `ignore_empty=True` to remove this warning.")
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fastai/data_block.py:461: UserWarning: Your validation set is empty. If this is by design, use `split_none()`
                 or pass `ignore_empty=True` when labelling to remove this warning.
  or pass `ignore_empty=True` when labelling to remove this warning.""")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fastai/data_block.py in get_label_cls(self, labels, label_cls, label_delim, **kwargs)
    264         if label_delim is not None:             return MultiCategoryList
--> 265         try: it = index_row(labels,0)
    266         except: raise Exception("""Can't infer the type of your targets. 

7 frames
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fastai/data_block.py in get_label_cls(self, labels, label_cls, label_delim, **kwargs)
    265         try: it = index_row(labels,0)
    266         except: raise Exception("""Can't infer the type of your targets. 
--> 267 It's either because your data source is empty or because your labelling function raised an error.""")
    268         if isinstance(it, (float, np.float32)): return FloatList
    269         if isinstance(try_int(it), (str, Integral)):  return CategoryList

Exception: Can't infer the type of your targets. 
It's either because your data source is empty or because your labelling function raised an error.
```

I do not understand why it throws this error when both directories are clearly populated with images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you make sure that your `path` variable set to /content/Food-101/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem:

```
data = ImageDataBunch.from_folder('/content/Food-101/images', train='/content/Food-101/images/train', test='/content/Food-101/images/test', valid_pct=0.2, ds_tfms=get_transforms(), size=224)
```